# Remove certain parts of web page using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, httplib2

I am trying to read links from a page, but I am getting more links than desired.
What I am doing is:

```
http = httplib2.Http()
status, page= http.request('page address')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
For link in soup:
 if link.has_attr('href'):
    print(link['href'])
```

I inspected the page and noticed that it has two main components:

```
<div id="main">
<aside id="secondary">
```

The links that I don't want are coming from what is inside `<aside id="secondary">`. What is the easiest way to only get links from `<div id="main">`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select `<a>` links that are under `<div id="main">` you can use CSS selector:

```
for a in soup.select('div#main a'):
    print(a)
```

---

For links only that have `href=` attribute:

```
for a in soup.select('div#main a[href]'):
    print(a['href'])
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `find_all` operator of beautifulsoup:

```
my_links = soup.find_all("a", {"id":"main", "href":True})
my_links = [x["href"] for x in my_links]
```

Assuming your webpage contains links inside a parent `div`, you can do the following:

```
my_divs = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"main"})
my_links = [x.find_all("a", {"href":True}, recursive=False) for x in my_divs]
# flatten
my_links = [x for y in my_links for x in y]
# extract hrefs
my_links = [x["href"] for x in my_links]
```